# ExtJs Error: no method 'loadData'

Tags: javascript, extjs, tree, loaddata

Im trying to load a tree with data but i get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'loadData'
```

this is my code

```
function ReadTree() {
        try {
            objHandler.ReadAssets(function (serverResponse) {
                if (serverResponse.error == null) {
                    var result = serverResponse.result;
                    if (result.length > 2) {

                        treestore.loadData(Ext.decode(result));

                       }
                }
                else {
                    alert(serverResponse.error.message);
                }
            }); //eo serverResponse
        } //eo try
        catch (e) {
            alert(e.message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: right before it


   var treestore = new  Ext.data.TreeStore ( {
  
    fields:['Title', 'IpAdress', 'Description'],
    data:[]

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TreeStore does not inherit from `Ext.data.Store` and thus does not have a `loadData` method. Both TreeStore and Store inherit from `Ext.data.AbstractStore` which defines a `load` method only. Therefore TreeStore has a load method, so I think you'll have to use that instead.

Comment: thank you so much,i dont have the error anymore..but i dont have any data loaded either :(

Comment: @astrocybernaute - You have to set up a proxy on the store because the TreeStore's load will use whatever proxy it was configured with: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.data.proxy.Proxy.html

Comment: ok thanks a lot, but im just starting in this, would u plz point me to an example that can help me..i appreciate

Comment: No worries. Check out this example: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/tree/reorder.html and the js used: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/tree/reorder.js

Comment: The proxy essentially sets up the necessary code to make a connection to your server.

Comment: i did this     :           
    var treestore = new  Ext.data.TreeStore ( {
    fields:['Title', 'Adress', 'Description'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users'
        }
    }

});     


                           but still not working :(

Comment: help on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328355/cant-see-the-data-inside-the-grid) please;thx