# How to debug Extjs store url: path with firebug?

Tags: extjs, tree, grid, extjs4

I am using the [**browser-layout**](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html) example for my application.

I'm trying to add a [**tree grid**](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2/examples/tree/treegrid.html) to it.  I defined a new class, but when I call my tree grid I can see the grid but no data inside.

What I'm trying to do is define the tree grid in a separate file.  My main file is the `layout-browser.js` and I need to add this (and others) in the tabs I have in it. What might I be doing wrong?

here is my code:

```
Ext.require([
'Ext.data.*',
'Ext.grid.*',
'Ext.tree.*'
]);

Ext.define('Task', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'task', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'user', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'duration', type: 'string' }
    ]
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    model: 'Task',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        //the store will get the content from the .json file
        url: 'treegrid.json'
    },

    folderSort: true
});



var tree = new Ext.tree.Panel({
title: 'Core Team Projects',
store : store,

columns:[
{
    header: 'Task',
    dataIndex: 'task',
    width: 80
},{
    header: 'Duration',
    width: 80,
    dataIndex: 'duration',
    //align: 'center',
    //sortType: 'asFloat'

},{
    header: 'Assigned To',
    width: 80,
    dataIndex: 'user'
}] 
});


Ext.define("Ext.app.myTreeGrid", {
    extend: "Ext.panel.Panel",


width: 300,
height : 300,
items: [tree]

});
```

thank you for ur time and help

Comment: putt every DEFINE block of code in a separate file and use loader to load it, the execute files CREATE, VAR ... put in a seperate file, not a define file, and then when u check that everything loads try debugit! Also where is your reader! U need one for tree.

Comment: i have been doing this but it was too many files for me, and this works even if i put both in same files,tried it with others examples

Comment: i didn't see you use your app.mytregrid.. have you use it? like new Ext.app.my or Ext.create("Ext.app.my")?

Comment: yes i did, var tree1 = Ext.create('Ext.app.myTreeGrid');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
proxy:{
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'myTree.json',
},
reader:{
    type: 'ajax',
    root: 'nodes',
    record: 'leaf'
 }  
}); 


var myTree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    store: store,
    rootVisible: false,  
    border: false,
    renderTo:Ext.getBody() //missing

});  

JSON

  {

    children: [
        { text:"Clients", expanded: true,
            children: [{ text:"MAIN", leaf: true }]
        }
    ]
  }
```

Here is an working example, u can define myTree and call it in your Browser-layout!

[image: ScreenShot]

Go to firebug NET console, refresh the page and search for treeGrid.json,
[image]
Hover over with mouse to see full URL
[image]
Update store with correct path from localstore to a folder with your .json

[image]
Try now!

Comment: thanks a lot, ive done some modifications and changed my question..kindly take a look

Comment: whan i add the reader it dosnt change anything, plus im trying to build a treegrid but ur example is for a simple tree right?

Comment: do you see treegrid.json succesfully loading in firebug?

Comment: didnt find it,dosnt seem it was loaded at all.just to make cause i have so many files, sure where can i see it ?

Comment: if you dont see it in console go to Firefox firebug NET console, there you can see a whole URL...

Comment: when i use ur exact code, i get to see the tree and nodes icons,but without text!!

Comment: sorry, renderTo:Ext.getBody(), missing! try to create correct path to your .json file.

Comment: i dont render to my getbdy,i add it to my tabs items ,so wasnt this, and im sure of the json path

Comment: No i ment for my tree example shown up, newer mind. If you say that you do not see even "bad" loading of your .json, then this means that your store isnt correct, or it isnt properly loaded. Its hard to see what is wrong without whole example, i have tried example from Sencha Examples, and it works for me. Did you created this: Ext.define("Ext.app.myTreeGrid"... somewhere???, chech that your store is loaded throught <script... in HTML.

Comment: yes i did and i can see the grid but no data inside, and i cant find the treegrid.json nor an error saying its not loaded,and i have been trying the sencha example and ur example.  i always have problems with trees, would it be something else causing me problems?? i dont know some configuration or something!!this is driving me crazy

Comment: i give up..have a more important issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346318/how-can-i-convert-frm-php-to-c-or-json-extjs)

Comment: would u take a look at my [current issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453312/show-different-item-on-selectionchange-on-a-grid) ,thanks