# How can I convert frm php to c# or json?

Tags: php, .net, extjs, tree, extjs4

I am using the [browser-layout](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html) example for my application

I'm trying to add a [two trees](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2/examples/tree/two-trees.html)  to it.

I'm trying to define the twotrees  in a separate file, my main file is the layout-browser.js and i need to add this (and others) in the tabs I have in it.

**The problem is that I'm using .net and the example is using php**

How can I make this work in .net?

Here is my code:

```
Ext.require(['*']);

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'get-nodes.php'
    },
    root: {
        text: 'Ext JS',
        id: 'src',
        expanded: true
    },
    folderSort: true,
    sorters: [{
        property: 'text',
        direction: 'ASC'
    }]
});

var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    id: 'tree',
    store: store,
    width: 250,
    height: 300,
    columnWidth: 0.5,
    viewConfig: {
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop',
            appendOnly: true
        }
    }
   // ,renderTo: document.body
});

var store2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'get-nodes.php'
    },
    root: {
        text: 'Custom Ext JS',
        id: 'src',
        expanded: true,
        children: []
    },
    folderSort: true,
    sorters: [{
        property: 'text',
        direction: 'ASC'
    }]
});

var tree2 = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    id: 'tree2',
    width: 250,
    height: 300,
    columnWidth: 0.5,
    store: store2,
    viewConfig: {
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop',
            appendOnly: true
        }
    }
   // ,renderTo: document.body
});


Ext.define("Ext.app.myTwoTrees",{
extend:"Ext.panel.Panel",

width : 600,
height: 350,
layout: 'column',
items: [
         tree , tree2
       ]

});
```

I call it in my tab like this:

```
 Ext.create('Ext.app.myTwotrees')
```

here is the get-nodes.php

```
<?php
// from php manual page
function formatBytes($val, $digits = 3, $mode = 'SI', $bB = 'B'){ //$mode == 'SI'|'IEC', $bB == 'b'|'B'
   $si = array('', 'K', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E', 'Z', 'Y');
   $iec = array('', 'Ki', 'Mi', 'Gi', 'Ti', 'Pi', 'Ei', 'Zi', 'Yi');
   switch(strtoupper($mode)) {
       case 'SI' : $factor = 1000; $symbols = $si; break;
       case 'IEC' : $factor = 1024; $symbols = $iec; break;
       default : $factor = 1000; $symbols = $si; break;
   }
   switch($bB) {
      case 'b' : $val *= 8; break;
      default : $bB = 'B'; break;
   }
  for($i=0;$i<count($symbols)-1 && $val>=$factor;$i++)
       $val /= $factor;
  $p = strpos($val, '.');
   if($p !== false && $p > $digits) $val = round($val);
   elseif($p !== false) $val = round($val, $digits-$p);
   return round($val, $digits) . ' ' . $symbols[$i] . $bB;
}

// grab the custom params
$path = isset($_REQUEST['path'])&&$_REQUEST['path'] == 'extjs' ? '../../../' : '../../';

$node = isset($_REQUEST['node']) ? $_REQUEST['node'] : '';
   $isXml = isset($_REQUEST['isXml']);

if(strpos($node, '..') !== false){
   die('Nice try buddy.');
}

$nodes = array();
$directory = $path.$node;
   if (is_dir($directory)){
       $d = dir($directory);
        while($f = $d->read()){
            if($f == '.' || $f == '..' || substr($f, 0, 1) == '.') continue;

    $filename = $directory . '/' . $f;
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
    $lastmod = date('M j, Y, g:i a', filemtime($filename));

    if(is_dir($directory.'/'.$f)){
        $qtip = 'Type: Folder<br />Last Modified: '.$lastmod;
        $nodes[] = array(
            'text' => $f,
            'id'   => $node.'/'.$f,
            'cls'  => 'folder'
        );
    } else {
        $size = formatBytes(filesize($filename), 2);
        $qtip = 'Type: JavaScript File<br />Last Modified: '.$lastmod.'<br />Size: '.$size;
        $nodes[] = array(
            'text' => $f,
            'id'   => $node.'/'.$f,
            'leaf' => true,
            'cls'  => 'file'
        );
    }
}
$d->close();
}

if ($isXml) {
    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
    $root = $xmlDoc->appendChild($xmlDoc->createElement("nodes"));
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $xmlNode = $root->appendChild($xmlDoc->createElement("node"));
    $xmlNode->appendChild($xmlDoc->createElement("text", $node['text']));
    $xmlNode->appendChild($xmlDoc->createElement("id", $node['id']));
    $xmlNode->appendChild($xmlDoc->createElement("cls", $node['cls']));
    $xmlNode->appendChild($xmlDoc->createElement("leaf", isset($node['leaf'])));
}
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
$xmlDoc->formatOutput = true;
echo $xmlDoc->saveXml();
} else {
    echo json_encode($nodes);
}
```

Comment: This question is asking a lot. What you should do is try to convert it yourself and then come back here with specific questions about problems you're having with the process of conversion.

Comment: dont even know how to start,im barely starting in .net, and cant really understand this php code. im asking for a way to do it or to come around it and still get the same results, i dont care about the data or anything,just need the drag and drop between trees to work

Comment: This is not a "help me write my code" site, but a "help me solve this problem" site. If you don't know how to code, you should look into some tutorials first. Buy some books... get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you break the problem into two pieces:

1) change `url: 'get-nodes.php'` to `url: 'my-dotnet-url` and make the .NET page return static JSON or XML (hardcode the values to the tree)

That will confirm all your javascript, resources, etc. is working properly and that you are only asking a .NET question about how to output certain data.

2) Then find a .NET example that will let you create JSON or XML from wherever you are getting data (I'm guessing probably a database).  You just need the output to look like your static data that worked correctly.  If you don't know much PHP or .NET learning .NET to get your output correct would be easier than trying to port over that example.  If you get stuck, I'd repost a different question and ask how to output the data that results from that static file dynamically and don't have the extjs complication involved!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Dextop](http://dextop.codaxy.com/showcase/). It's an application framework for connection between ASP.NET and Ext JS.